# Has anyone been able to create working vector maps/lanelet2 maps for Autoware.ai

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying for months to find software that can create acceptable road definition maps for Autoware. The Autoware vector map creator seems to be localized for Japan. I don't know if it properly configures them for use anywhere else. I have also used Autoware's lanelet2 map creator with some success but I am unable to find a working planner that uses Lanelet2 maps and not vector maps.

Has anyone been successful creating their owns maps and running an Autoware planner outside of Japan? Does anyone know of any open source software or paid services that provide such maps in Florida?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351978/has-anyone-been-able-to-create-working-vector-maps/lanelet2-maps-for-autoware.ai./) by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2020-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try [ASSURE Mapping tool](https://github.com/hatem-darweesh/assuremappingtools).
You can enter GPS origin and it will save lanelet2 correctly. beside other cool features.

But currently Autoware's lanelet2 loader only uses MGRS, which has a fixed GPS origin.

I have developed a workaround in my [fork](https://gitlab.com/hatem-darweesh-autoware.ai/common/-/blob/openplanner.1.13/map_file/launch/lanelet2_map_loader.launch) from version 1.13, which you can use UTM projection. and [OpenPlanner](https://gitlab.com/hatem-darweesh-autoware.ai) can use it too. branch "openplanner.1.13"

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2020-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-05-18**:
@Hatem Very nice! Would you consider creating a merge request to the upstream fork to add this feature?

**Comment by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on 2020-05-19**:
I have used the assure mapping tool, but I am a bit confused on the coordinates required. Should the loaded point cloud be expressed in MGRS coordinates(or a local UTM with the workaround) to match the lanelet2 map?

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2020-05-19**:
@Josh Whitley I will tested with 1.14 , then send a MR.

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2020-05-19**:
@Patrick N. If you have the origin of the point cloud as GPS coordinate, you don't need to worry.
I guess this is one of the mapping output.

it doesn't matter MGRS or UTM. the most important thing is to use the same coordinate projector  for both saving the lanelet2 and loading the lanelet2.
but the MGRS implementation inside Autoware doesn't accept origin. so it only convert with the internal fixed origin.
That is why I added the UTM option, (I didn't want to change the original implementation so I don't confuse if someone is actually using it)

if you have a map I can help you convert it and load it using Autoware. I guess that will make everything clear.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try contacting AutonomouStuff or Mandli. They do this routinely for customers (I used to work at AS). The process is very complex and involves a lot of manual labelling. You definitely won't find an automated tool that will do it for you.

Regarding using the maps, Autoware.ai contains a lanelet2aisan tool which will convert Lanelet2 maps to the proprietary Aisan "vector" map format. Also, as of version 1.13, it also contains tools to directly load Lanelet2 maps without using the Aisan format.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-05-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another tool that I found decent is [MapToolbox](https://github.com/autocore-ai/MapToolbox) which utilizes Unity.

---

Originally posted by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) with karma: 123 on 2020-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1